# Is DQM latency during READ always two cycle and independent from CL in SDR SDRAM?

Tags: sdram

Reading SDR SDRAM datasheets, i found (and had been surprised) that during READs (with Burst Length >=2) DQM latency is always two cycles.

That statement is given explicitly at least in one [datasheet](http://www.issi.com/WW/pdf/42-45S81600F-16800F.pdf) (pp. 29-30):
[image]

(Other datasheets are speaking about two cycle DQM latency on read too.)

But i found no explicit or even implicit statement about relationship between DQM latency and CAS latency.

**Is READ DQM latency independent from CL?**

*Why independent, if it is? And why it is exactly of two cycles?*

Comment: That's what the datasheet says. And it affects the DQ I/O buffers directly and nothing else, so adjusting the DQM pipeline length to track different CL would just be adding unnecessary complexity.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Then why two cycles, not one or three? Also, with two cycle long latency how to deal with CL=1 (not rare for automotive grade memory)?

Comment: Good questions. (1)  I often latch an input signal directly in an IO block for the best I/O (setup and hold) timings, then re-register it one cycle later at the point of use to eliminate the internal routing delay. The same may be true here.  (2) Simply issue DQM one cycle earlier.

Comment: @BrianDrummond That DQM latency (=2clk) is defined (and i think applicable) only during READs. During WRITE DQM latency is zero. During other operations it is undefined. With CL=1, for the first data in a burst to be masked, you need to issue DQM=H before issuing the READ command itself. If previous command was WRITE (DQM lat=0) that DQM=H conflicts with it.  If previous command was other the next behavior is unpredictable. Therefore, this is not a (correct) solution.

Comment: Then you will have to check that case in a datasheet for a device where CL=1. That case is not explained in either the linked datasheet or the Micron one I have here, though the latter does show examples where you have to insert a NOP between READ and WRITEs.

Comment: @BrianDrummond It looks like READ DQM pipeline lives its own life parallel to all other logic. It is even not affected by CS#... (From Micron, ISSI, Winbond, Alliance, and Lapis/Rohm datasheets i read and Micron's SDRAM Verilog model i examined at-a-glance.) But why 2clk? i think the reason (if any) is totally historic now...